# Prove that $\lim_{r \to 1} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(re^{i\theta}) d\theta = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(e^{i\theta}) d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

...if $f$ is continuous in an open set $\Omega$ containing the unit circle $T$.

Is the proof something along the line of: $T$ is compact hence $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $D(z;\epsilon) \subset \Omega$, $\forall z \in T$ hence $K:=\{z:1-\epsilon/2 \leq |z| \leq 1 + \epsilon/2\} \subset \Omega$ so that $|f|$ is bounded by say $M$ on $K$ and then use Dominated Convergence Theorem?

If it's correct, is there a more obvious proof?

Thank you.

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, if $\epsilon >0$, we may choose $n$ large enough so that $\left | f((1-\frac{1}{n})e^{i\theta })-f(e^{i\theta }) \right |<\frac{\epsilon}{2\pi }$.

Comment: I would say that just a bit differently: $f$ is continous on $\Omega$ implies $f$ is continuous on the closed unit disc. Because that disc is compact, $f$ is uniformly continous on that disc. It follows that as functions on the circle, $f(re^{it}) \to f(e^{it})$ unifomly as $r\to 1^-.$